# CodeIgniter -Error Call to a member function model() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a registering from. Whenever I try to insert data to db it throws this error.

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   property: insert_ctrl::$insert_model Filename:
>   controllers/insert_ctrl.php Line Number: 38
>        Fatal error: Call to a member function form_insert() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\NewProject\application\controllers\insert_ctrl.php on
>   line 38

This is my insert_ctrl.php

```
<?php

class insert_ctrl extends  CI_Controller{

    function _construct()
    {
        parent :: _construct();
        $this->insert_model->form_insert($data);

    }

    function index()
    {
        //Including validation library
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class ="error">','</div>');

        //Validating name field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dname','Username','required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('demail','Email','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dmobile','Mobile No.');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('daddress','Adress','required|min_length[10]|max_length[50]');

            if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('insert_view');
            }
            else {
                //Setting values for db table
                $data=array(
                    'Student_Name'=>$this->input->post('dname'),
                    'Student_Email'=>$this->input->post('demail'),
                    'Student_Mobile'=>$this->input->post('dmoblie'),
                    'Student_Address'=>$this->input->post('daddress')

                );
                //Transfering data to model
                $this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
                //loading view
                $this->load->view('insert_view');
            }
        }
    }

//insert_model.php

<?php
class insert_model extends  CI_Model{
    function _construct()
    {
        parent :: _construct();


    }

    function form_insert($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('student',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine just change your constructor code into
    $this->load->model('insert_model');

Comment: I did that. But still it gives an error

Comment: This is not even entering to insert_model.php Please help meee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My controller-insert_ctrl.php

```
class insert_ctrl extends  CI_Controller{

function __construct()
{
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->load->model('insert_model');

}

function index()
{

        $this->insert_model->form_insert();
        echo "Clear";


}
```

}

My Model- insert_model.php

```
class insert_model extends  CI_Model{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent :: __construct();


    }

    function form_insert()
    {
        echo "model loaded Successfully";
    }
}
```

This model and controller has been named exactly as your. Check how the model has been loaded and called.

You can overcome the memory limit error by adding the following line of code on top of your php file.

> ini_set("memory_limit","512M");

Answer (score 2):

You call wrong model function:

```
You call $this->load->model('Insert_model');
```

It means your model is Insert_model

instead of this:

```
 $this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
```

You use

```
$this->Insert_model->form_insert($data);
```

Change your constructor code to

```
function _construct()
    {
        parent :: _construct();
        $this->load->model('insert_model');

    }
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. I just did it wrong . I changed like this but still it gives me the same error .

Comment: please submit your model code and change your model name

Comment: but still you not change the model name

Comment: @Akisha i add few line in my code you need to change your constructor code

Comment: Sorry I did change in my project just didn't change here. Btw thank you soo much I'll try this one

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

> $autoload['libraries'] = array();

to

> $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

in `config\autoload.php`

Answer (score -1):

Add this line: `$this->load->model('modelName');`

```
function __construct()
{
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->load->model('modelName');

}
```